# How to create more than one link (or a second different link) out of a filled out google survey?

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to copy the link to an existing questionnaire that is already filled with answers, but want a different link (not the existing link) to that questionnaire with the same answers (without having to fill out the same answers again!).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the survey is personalised, then the link you received is also personalised.  It would then be encoded in some way so that they know it is your response.  That means that you can not have two copies of it.

> Settings
> The Settings allow you to customize various features, such as
>
> whether the email addresses of the respondents are collected
> if respondents can return later to change their answers
> if they can submit multiple times or only once (in this case the respondent must be logged in with their account)
> if it shows a progress bar, and
> if the questions are shuffled randomly.

From [How to Make a Google Form Survey](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-google-form-survey-google-forms-tutorial/)

Comment: Thaks Rohit! What if I have the Google Form out which individual surveys are made. Can I create and fill in a survey that is not personalized, which would allow me to then have more than one link out of a filled out survey?